# Constructor using parameters from objects

Tags: c#

I have a C# constructor that uses a variable of an object from another class. But the constructor starts before creating the object. So how can I load the object before the constructor starts?

```
public class model
{
     public model()
        {
         Initialize();
         }

         private void Initialize()
         {
           int a=0;
           a=device.number;
           }

    Anotherclass device;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never assigning a value to your `device` variable.
If it comes from another class, you need to receive it as a parameter in the constructor:

```
public model(AnotherClass deviceParameter)
{
    device = deviceParameter; 
    Initialize();
}
```

If it's self-contained, you need to call its constructor before using it.

```
public model()
{
     Initialize();
}

private void Initialize()
{
     device = new AnotherClass();
     int a=0;
     a=device.number;
}
```